# Sql Exec Problemas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Bom, eu estou tentando executar o comando abaixo, porém está dando sempre erro, alguém sabe  por que?

```
declare @maquinaCount varchar(max);
declare @maquinaOnline varchar(max);

select @maquinaCount = 'select count(id) from Indigo_Nextel_Portabilidade_Dev6.bko.OnlineMachine';

select @maquinaOnline = 'select count(id) from Indigo_Nextel_Portabilidade_Dev6.bko.OnlineMachine where bol_online = 1';
exec(@maquinaOnline);
exec(@maquinaCount);
insert into TB_METRICA(Metrica_Nome, Metrica_MaquinaQuant, Metrica_MaquinaOnline) values('Nextel Portabilidade', exec(@maquinaCount), exec(@maquinaOnline));
```

Comment: Ué, qual erro? Se você não especificar o erro fica bem difícil sugerir uma resposta

Comment: as variaveis não são efetuadas.

Comment: E tem algum motivo especial pra você usar exec ao invés de só jogar o valor em variáveis?

Answer (score 0):

Pela estrutura do código e pelas *tags* da pergunta, você está fazendo tudo isso em *sql* mesmo, no próprio banco de dados. Sendo assim, podes fazer a consulta diretamente, sem precisar armazenar o comando em variáveis e executar.
Assim, já poderia setar `@maquinaCount` e `@maquinaOnline` com as quantidades:

```
declare @maquinaCount int;
declare @maquinaOnline int;

select @maquinaCount = count(id) from Indigo_Nextel_Portabilidade_Dev6.bko.OnlineMachine    
select @maquinaOnline = count(id) from Indigo_Nextel_Portabilidade_Dev6.bko.OnlineMachine where bol_online = 1

insert into TB_METRICA(Metrica_Nome, Metrica_MaquinaQuant, Metrica_MaquinaOnline)
values('Nextel Portabilidade', @maquinaCount, @maquinaOnline)
```

Quanto ao erro que está recebendo, provavelmente os campos `MaquinaQuant` e `Metrica_MaquinaOnline` são de tipo numérico, e os declarados no seu código são `varchar(max)`